# Serial (TTY-like), synchronous user interaction with (rich) text view

Tags: android, textview

I'd like to use something like a [`TextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) to do serial/TTY/text terminal-like, synchronous user interaction. What I mean by that is I need the following operations:

- Add some new text (styled with various `Span`s) at the end
- Synchronously wait for the user to enter some further text (styled with some `Span`s) at the end, finished by a newline / some "Submit"-style button on the virtual keyboard / etc. No other parts of the text should be selectable, editable, etc.

Of course the second operation doesn't make any sense on the UI thread, so the way I imagine this, I'd have a separate thread that has synchronous code of the form

```
// NOT on the UI thread here
textui.addText("What's your name? ", 
    new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 
    new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED));
String name = textui.getLine(
    new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN),
    new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC));
textui.addText("Hello, ");
textui.addText(name, 
    new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD));
textui.addText("!");
```

Note that `getLine` should wait for the user to input, the user should be unable to edit the `What's your name?` part, and as the user is typing, his input should be in green italic. Here's some mockups:

1. After adding the first line:

   [image: 1]
2. User starts typing

   [image: 2]
3. User has submitted his input

   [image: 3]

One thing I've tried is using an `EditText` with an `InputFilter` to reject user edits until `getLine` is called and to disallow edits to any previous output, but this still allows the user to move the cursor around and select output as if it was input.

**EDITED TO ADD**: I got a close vote due to my question being 'unclear', so let me try to explain it another way. Imagine you had a console program that uses `System.out.println` and `System.console().readLine` and you wanted to replicate that exact UX inside an Android control (potentially surrounded by other Android controls), with the addition of styling.

Comment: I’m not sure I got this. Is there any reason why you can't just fire the action upon the button click / newline insertion, without ever leaving the UI thread?

Comment: @natario: I agree putting a synchronous API on top is the easier part; but that still leaves the part about having a text control that allows input only at the end and only until submitted, then allows adding uneditable output, then only allows further input after some method of it is called.

Comment: Ok - it's clear now!

Comment: Why don't you use multiple TextView + EditText wrapped in a LinearLayout?

Comment: @regev avraham: how would that work with a "prompt" paragraph that spans multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Added flags to allow/disallow editing and to specify if a field is single or multi-line. Moved custom `EditText` to separate class file. Fixed cursor movement issue.

Here is an approach that may work for you. I understand that you are looking for a TTY kind of capability. I am unsure what the synchronous part is about but here goes.

When editing is disallowed, the approach is to use the custom `EditText` to eliminate the ability for the user to move around in a field and, from a hardware keyboard, to detect the enter key (field termination) and to inhibit the delete key. This is all done by the custom `EditText` defined in `TtyEditText.java`.

Control of the on-screen keyboard works a little differently and employs a `TextWatcher` to handle things.

The sample app simply cycles through three prompts and displays the information the user enters back to the screen using the types of `Spans` you mentioned in your question.

Here is a quick video where editing is not allowed.

[Demo video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2mA0.gif)

<s>There is one quirk with the use of the left and right arrow keys to move around within a field. The right arrow key works fine, but the left arrow key seems to want to move between fields instead of back within the field. I have explicitly disabled both until a solution is found even if this is an issue.</s>

According to [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation.html#Direction):

> Users can also navigate your app using the arrow keys on a keyboard (the behavior is the same as when navigating with a D-pad or trackball). The system provides a best-guess as to which view should be given focus in a given direction based on the layout of the views on screen. Sometimes, however, the system might guess wrong.

So, Android is guessing wrong? This has been solved by making completed fields non-focusable. The code has been corrected to handle cursor keys.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements TextWatcher, TtyEditText.FieldAction {
    private String mPrompts[] = new String[]{
            "What is your name? ",
            "What is your quest? ",
            "What is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow? "
    };
    private int mPromptIndex = -1;
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    private TtyEditText mCurrentField;

    // true-current field can be edited (backspace/selection); false-disallow field editing
    private final boolean mAllowEditing = true;
    // true input is single line EditText else multi-line
    private final boolean mSingleLine = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final ScrollView scrollView;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        scrollView = createViewGroup(); // Simple LinearLayout within ScrollView
        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) scrollView.getChildAt(0);
        setContentView(scrollView);

        // Get the ball rolling with first prompt.
        mCurrentField = generatePrompt(mLinearLayout);
    }

    // Create the next prompt field and place it at the bottom of the layout.
    private TtyEditText generatePrompt(LinearLayout layout) {
        final TtyEditText editText;
        final SpannableString s;

        if (++mPromptIndex >= mPrompts.length) {
            mPromptIndex = 0;
        }

        editText = createTtyEditText(mAllowEditing, mPrompts[mPromptIndex].length());
        s = styleText(mPrompts[mPromptIndex], new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),
                new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED));
        editText.setText(s);
        layout.addView(editText);

        editText.setSingleLine(mSingleLine);
        if (!mSingleLine) { // multi-line gets a "done" key.
            editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        }

        editText.addTextChangedListener(MainActivity.this);

        editText.requestFocus();

        InputMethodManager imm =
                (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

        return editText;
    }

    // Echo the user's input to the bottom of the layout.
    private void echoResponse(LinearLayout layout, String enteredText) {
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        SpannableString prefix;
        SpannableString input;

        prefix = styleText("You entered: ", new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL),
                new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK));
        input = styleText(enteredText, new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK));
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView.setTextSize(DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
        textView.setText(TextUtils.concat(prefix, input));
        layout.addView(textView);
    }

    // Invoked from our EditText subclass when the enter key is seen on single line EditText and
    // from this Activity on multiline EditText.
    @Override
    public void onEnter(TtyEditText editText) {
        final String s = editText.getText().toString();
        final String entry = s.substring(editText.getPromptLength(), s.length());

        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        editText.setFocusable(false);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        editText.setEnabled(false);
        echoResponse(mLinearLayout, entry);
        mCurrentField = generatePrompt(mLinearLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        if (mAllowEditing) {
            if (start < mPrompts[mPromptIndex].length()) {
                mCurrentField.removeTextChangedListener(this); // prevent infinite looping
                mCurrentField.setText(s);
                mCurrentField.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        } else if (after < count) { // Trying to delete, so don't allow it.
            mCurrentField.removeTextChangedListener(this); // prevent infinite looping
            mCurrentField.setText(s);
            mCurrentField.addTextChangedListener(this);
        }
    }

    // This method only does anything if the input field is multi-line.
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (mSingleLine) {
            return;
        }
        // Multi-line fields get a newline character inserted. Look for the newline, strip it
        // and that will complete field entry.
        int newlinePos = TextUtils.indexOf(s, "\n");
        if (newlinePos != -1) {
            mCurrentField.removeTextChangedListener(this); // prevent infinite looping
            s = TextUtils.concat(s.subSequence(0, newlinePos),
                    s.subSequence(newlinePos + 1, s.length()));
            mCurrentField.setText(s);
            onEnter(mCurrentField);
        }
    }

    // Add text to a TextView (could be an EditText) and apply spans for styling.
    private SpannableString styleText(String text, StyleSpan style,
                                      ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColor) {
        final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(text);

        s.setSpan(style, 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s.setSpan(foregroundColor, 0, text.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), s.length(), s.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), s.length(), s.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        return s;
    }

    // Create an empty LinearLayout within ScrollView.
    private ScrollView createViewGroup() {
        final ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(this);
        final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params =
                new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final int margins = convertDpToPixels(16f, this);

        params.setMargins(margins, margins, margins, margins);
        scroll.setLayoutParams(params);

        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        /* Bottom padding is set here due to a very strange interaction between the
           EditText, the soft keyboard, and the ScrollView. With zero padding, when
           input field abuts the top of the soft keyboard and the user anter a space,
           things get a little wacky with how things are handled. User input freezes and
           there are bad calls made to this app. The bottom padding fixes it, though.
        */
        linearLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, convertDpToPixels(16f, this));

        scroll.addView(linearLayout);

        return scroll;
    }

    // Create an instance of our subclass of EditText.
    private TtyEditText createTtyEditText(final boolean allowEditing, final int promptLength) {
        final TtyEditText editText;
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        editText = new TtyEditText(this);
        editText.setEditParams(allowEditing, promptLength);
        editText.setLayoutParams(params);
        editText.setTextSize(DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
        editText.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
                | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
        editText.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        editText.setFocusable(true);
        editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        return editText;
    }

    private static int convertDpToPixels(float dp, Context context) {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,
                context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    private static final float DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE = 18f;
}
```

**TtyEditText.java**

```
public class TtyEditText extends AppCompatEditText {
    boolean mAllowEditing = true;
    int mPromptLength = 0;

    // Interface to activity for the enter key. This can be expanded to accommodate other keys.
    FieldAction mFieldAction;

    public TtyEditText(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public TtyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TtyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mFieldAction = (FieldAction) context;
    }

    // Handle the "enter" and "delete" keys from hardware keyboards.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                mFieldAction.onEnter(this);
                return true;
        }
        super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        return false;
    }

    // Don't let the user move around in the field. If they try, put them back to the end.
    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        //on selection move cursor to end of text
        if (!mAllowEditing) { // No backspace/no cursor movement except to add to end
            setSelection(this.length());
        } else if (selStart < mPromptLength && this.getText().length() > 0) { // can't move into prompt area
            setSelection(mPromptLength);
        } else {
            super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
        }
    }

    public void setEditParams(boolean allowEditing, int promptLength) {
        mAllowEditing = allowEditing;
        mPromptLength = promptLength;
    }

    public int getPromptLength() {
        return mPromptLength;
    }

    interface FieldAction {
        public void onEnter(TtyEditText ttyEditText);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very promising! Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to edit the current input line: neither selecting nor backspace (either hardware or touch keyboard) works.

Comment: Also, I've changed the last line of `addStyledTextToView` to `et.setText(TextUtils.concat(et.getText(), s))` to align better with my real use case; I'm not sure if I should apply that edit to your answer here.

Comment: I think selecting inside the current input line is something I could live without; but backspace (of course, only up to the end of the previous output) definitely has to work for this to solve my problem.

Comment: I have intentionally disabled input line editing since I thought it was something you wanted. How should the editing of the current input line be handled? Just like a normal edittext?

Comment: And selection is ok? How about selection and deletion of selection? Sounds like a normal edit text but allow deletion of only characters that the user has entered.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like (of course, lines entered previously should not be editable, only the "current" one).

Comment: Sounds pretty straight-forward, but I am sure it will be a little more involved than I am thinking right now. It will be a little while before I can look at this (not real soon, but within the next 12 hours or so). I'll post an update to the answer when I have something.